# Multithreading || Java

Tags: java, string, multithreading, loops, arraylist

I've a program that's as follows below. I want three concurrent threads to add different Strings to `infiList` ("This", "is", "infinite") using thread synchronization.

I want to append certain threads also, for example;

- If the last word in `infiList` is currently “This”, the thread should append word “is” to `infiList`.
- If the last word in `infiList` is currently “is”, the thread should append word “infinite” to `infiList`.
- If the last word in `infiList` is currently “infinite”, or if `infiList` is still empty, the thread should append word “This” to `infiList`.
- At any time, `infiList` should contain “This” only at the beginning of the list or directly after an occurrence of “infinite”, “is” should occur in the list only directly after a “This”, and an “infinite” should
  occur only directly after an “is”.

Any help as to how to do this is appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Multithreading implements Runnable {

public static ArrayList<String> infiList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        String s = null;
        synchronized (infiList) {
            if(infiList.isEmpty())
                infiList.add("This");
            else
            {
                s = infiList.get(infiList.size()-1);

            if(s.equals("This"))
                infiList.add("is");
            else if(s.equals("is"))
                infiList.add("infinite");
            else if(s.equals("infinite"))
                infiList.add("This");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main (String args[]) {
    // Create three concurrent threads
    new Thread(new Multithreading()).start();
    new Thread(new Multithreading()).start();
    new Thread(new Multithreading()).start();

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very naive quick fix for the problem. Synchronized will obtain a lock, on the arraylist, check the element and insert it based on your rules. But due to your logic being depending on the last element while adding a element to the array while maintaning the order of the elements this is actually not multithreaded but a sequential program.

This is simply because, when multithreaded programs run, you don't care abount the sequentioning, because you can never guarentee it. In most cases you will go into a Divide and Conqueer style algorithm, where the algorithm will be split up into pieces and calculated in pieces.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        String s = null;
        synchronized (infiList) {
            if(infiList.isEmpty())
                infiList.add("This");
            else
            {
                s = infiList.get(infiList.size()-1);

            if(s.equals("This"))
                infiList.add("is");
            else if(s.equals("is"))
                infiList.add("infinite");
            else if(s.equals("infinite"))
                infiList.add("This");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How to utilize multithreading**

If we look at your example in another case, where you needed to calculate something before you put it into the array. This could lead to utilzing the multithreading performance better.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        String s = null;

        CalculateSomethingBig();

        synchronized (infiList) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If we play with the thought, that the primary runtime lies within `CalculateSomethingBig()`, this will now utilize more of the computers multitasking capabilities, because more of the threads will use time to calculate and utilize processing power then to wait on a lock being released.

**How to get output**

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Create three concurrent threads
    new Thread(new Multithreading()).start();
    new Thread(new Multithreading()).start();
    new Thread(new Multithreading()).start();

    for(String s : infiList)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: When I try to run this, I get multiple errors `"Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Multithreading.run(Multithreading.java:17)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"`

Comment: But your loop will run forever... or maybe infinite :)

Comment: What's the best way to implement it without the use of while(true)?

Comment: do a for loop that runs 100 times or something similar :)

Comment: Then print it? It seems like your Java skills are not at an level, where i would recommend playing around with threads.

Comment: Updated my answer, but still learn the basics of walking before you learn to fly. Most universities teach Concurrency as a master level course for a reason.

Comment: Thank me by reading My explanation on why this is not multithreading